# Embed python into looker

Tags: python-3.x, looker

Is there a natural way to wrap Python code to display in Looker?

The ideal dataflow for my problem is SQL DB->python-> looker, or alternatively, looker->python-> looker. 
I am hoping to embed a.py into `lookML` so that I can automate python analysis, ready to display in looker.

Comment: You can't embed python into LookML,

Answer (score 1):

You can't call Python code from Looker. Depending on the database you are using, you may want to look into creating a UDF within that database and then call it using SQL.

Answer (score -1):

You can't embed a Python code in Looker Studio.

- but if you can use a custom URL or a Custom deployement your dashbaord then you use an HTML iframe code that code i have mentioned in below example

For Ex:

```
<iframe width="600" height="450" src=" " frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: Note that the question is about Looker not Looker Studio